# Jquery Validation and CSS

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, jquery

I have multiple DIV's on a page,which contain form fields.Some of them are required and some not.When a user jumps from one div to other by entering data.I have to validate the required fields are satisfied and change the CSS of that completed DIV.If required fields are not met,i should not change the css effect.I would like to approach this with Jquery.So,Can someone provide a good and clean design to approach.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle so we can see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery validator](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) 
plugin for validating your content.

Once your div looses focus you can then check if validation has passed or not, if not then dont apply the css or else apply css.

Sample code:

```
$("#divid").validate({
    onfocusout: false,    //once div looses focus validate
    rules: {
        //your rules go here
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.I haven't started coding yet.I wanted to get an understanding before putting my head down.One Question here,because I have multiple form fields on a page,how do i distinguish between required and optional fields.Do I have check the fields against a file or assign an attribute (req).  Thanks for J Validator.

Comment: to the element you will add a class called as required

Comment: fields which are required add class="required" only to those, leave the other optional field as it is

Comment: Yeah,taught so.Thanks mprabhat.

Comment: Hey,how can this be handled during onload?On-load meaning I am populating the form with the data i already have respresnting it to the user.So,how can I check if my DIV has failed validation in this case? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jquery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery validation you can create your own method to validate a group of controls, I use this approach to wrap elements in a div or fieldset with the class name "validationGroup".  Then, when I trigger an event from within the group I navigate up the DOM to the parent element with the class name and validate everything underneath.  Using this approach, you can control/limit the validation to the controls in the current div being edited.

function ValidateAndSubmit(evt)
{
    var isValid = true;

```
// Get Validator & Settings
var validator = $("#aspnetForm").validate();
var settings = validator.settings;

// Find the parent control that contains the elements to be validated
var $group = $(evt.currentTarget).parents('.validationGroup');

// Grab all the input elements (minus items listed below)
$group
    .find(":input")
    .not(":submit, :reset, :image, [disabled]")
    .not(settings.ignore)
    .each(function (i, item)
    {
        // Don't validate items without rules
        if (!validator.objectLength($(item).rules()))
            return true;

        if (!$(item).valid())
            isValid = false;
    });

// If any control is the group fails, prevent default actions (aka: Submit)
if (!isValid) {
    evt.preventDefault();
}

return isValid;
```

}